# can I compare with where two entire json values?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have a JSON field in the stadiums table (mysql) named location, can i compare it with another json like below?...

```
select *from stadiums where location = '{"lat":40, "lng":3}';
```

*The query doesnt return me any error, but doesnt return me any row when there is in fact a coincidence

Comment: What database are you using and what are you storing the `location` fields as? String, Text, JSON?

Comment: mysql, and a json field, location is the json field

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function:

```
SELECT * FROM stadiums WHERE location = CAST('{"lat":40, "lng":3}' AS JSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) functions that you can use to search JSON fields.

Try something like:

```
select * from stadiums where
  JSON_EXTRACT(location, '$.lat') = 40 and
  JSON_EXTRACT(location, '$.lng') = 3;
```

Comment: thanks for comment!
I aready compared separately, I just wanted to know if there is a easier way to compare json